# Is there a simple way to determine which thread the current method is running on?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

The title says it all. I would like to be able to simply detect if work is being executed on the UI thread. Also, if the method is not running on the UI/main thread, can I determine what other thread that it might be? I would like to use this information for debugging purposes. Thanks!

Comment: Look at [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815929/how-can-a-method-know-if-its-running-on-the-ui-thread)

Answer (score -1):

In a UWP app, you can check and store the value of the [Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId?view=netframework-4.7.2) property when your app starts and then compare the current value of the same property with the stored value to determine whether you are on the same thread.

Or use the [CoreDispatcher.HasThreadAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync) property to determine whether the current thread can safely update the UI.